# MySQL Variable Database Name Syntax Error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set a database name for a MySQL query. I've been able to get my first query to work, but the second I'm struggling to figure out where my syntax error is. I'm guessing it has something to do with the variable, but I'm stuck.

```
SET @db = CONCAT('SELECT client_databases.database_name
FROM client_databases
JOIN jobs ON jobs.organisation_id = client_databases.organisation_id
WHERE jobs.transaction_reference="K01-REC0000001"');

SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT receipts_lines.id, product_code, product_name, receipts_lines.is_putaway
    FROM ', @db ,'.receipts
    JOIN ', @db ,'.receipts_lines ON receipts_lines.receipt_id = receipts.id
    WHERE reference_number="K01-REC0000001"');

PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: What's the database name? You are using a whole query as the value of `@db`.

Comment: yes, the whole query as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this. Where you select into @db the databasename and use this to build your stmt

```
SELECT client_databases.database_name INTO @db
FROM client_databases
JOIN jobs ON jobs.organisation_id = client_databases.organisation_id
WHERE jobs.transaction_reference="K01-REC0000001";

SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT receipts_lines.id, product_code, product_name, receipts_lines.is_putaway
    FROM ', @db ,'.receipts
    JOIN ', @db ,'.receipts_lines ON receipts_lines.receipt_id = receipts.id
    WHERE reference_number="K01-REC0000001"');

PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```